# Save the position using Shared preferences in android

Tags: android, position, global-variables, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener

I have to develop one android application.Here i have to set the position here:

```
ar = new LinearLayout(this);
ar.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ar.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
ar.setLayoutParams(artiLayoutParams);
ar.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
ar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
ar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_selector));
ar.setId(position);
position++;
ar.setOnClickListener(mArticleClick);
```

After that i have to get the position and display the list of images depends upon these position.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {

        int object = v.getId();

        String articletitle = Appscontent.Sub_arraylist.get(object).toString();
        String articleimage = Appscontent.Sub_arraylistimage.get(object).toString();

        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubCate.class);
        in.putExtra("Title", articletitle);
        in.putExtra("Image", articleimage);

        startActivity(in);
    }
};
```

Here i have to save these postion using shared preferences or global variable..how can i save it ????

pls give me some idea ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save value(position):

```
 SharedPreferences setPref = getSharedPreferences("Packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    setPref.edit().putInt("position", your position).commit();
```

To fetch value(position):

```
 SharedPreferences getPref = getSharedPreferences("Packagename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  int pos = getPref.getInt("position",0);
```

Answer (score 1):

use shared preference to save

```
SharedPreferences pos= getSharedPreferences("position", 0);
Editor ed=pos.edit();
ed.putString("pos",object);
ed.commit();
```

and get it as

```
SharedPreference pos=getSharedPreference("position",0);
int id=pos.getInt("pos",1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To save a value in a key:

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putString(key, value);
  editor.commit();
}
```